Conditional probability - finding set of acceptable $p$ values.
I was given this question today by a colleague who showed it to her high school Mathematics students (final year, high academic standard):
For two events, $A$ and $B$ it is known that $P(A)=0.2$ and $P(B^c)=0.6$.
If $P(A^c|B)=p^2$ what is the set of possible values for $p$?
The colleague had not written a solution, so I came up with the following (but have a few doubts about the validity of some of the steps).
$P(B)=1-P(B^c)=0.4$
$P(A^c|B)=p^2$ and therefore $P(A|B)=1-p^2$
$P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)\times P(B)=0.4(1-p^2)$
Now, $P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)$ so $0.4(1-p^2)\leq 0.2$
Which means $p^2\geq \frac{1}{2}$
Edit incorrect line removed here - thanks @DavidK
By a different argument, $P(A|B)\geq P(A)$ so $1-p^2 \geq 0.2$ which means $p^2 \leq \frac{4}{5}$
Therefore a second limitation on $p$ is $\frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}}\leq p \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$
Putting the two restrictions together gives $p\in [\frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}]\cup [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}]$
I am not at all confident of my working here, but even more so, I am really wondering if the negative $p$ values make any sense in the context of a probability question. My instinct is that it is acceptable since the probabilities are given in terms of $p^2$.
So, have I made a really fundamental error in assumptions here and, if so, can this problem still be solved?

How do you get $\mathbb{P}[A^c|B]=p^2$?

Knowing that $P(B,|,A^c)=p^2$ is not the same as knowing $P(A^c,|,B)=p^2)$.  In general, $P(X,|,Y)\neq P(Y,|,X)$.

Ah, yes... thanks to you both. I think I have mis-typed the question!

I'm going to delete this question and re-post once I've figured out what it should say. Thanks for helping me see the error so quickly.

Should say:  I share your unease regarding the negative values, but mostly because of the notation.  Calling the parameter $p$ strongly suggests that it is intended to represent a probability, hence could not be negative.  Of course, nothing in the problem statement declares that it is a probability, hence it certainly could be negative, but the notation seems unnecessarily misleading.

Thanks. I think I found the error in the notation (had $A^c$ and $B$ the wrong way around), have edited.

Your inequality algebra seems off.  Knowing that $.4\times (1-p^2)≤.2$ implies $(1-p^2)≤ \frac 12 \implies p^2≥\frac 12\implies |p|≥\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$.  Whereas you state the opposite.

You write $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \leq p \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$,
which is incorrect, although later, judging from your statement that
$p\in \left[\frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right] \cup \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right]$,
you appear to understand that the correct statement is actually
"$p \leq \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$ or $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \leq p$."
But the more serious flaw is the incorrect assertion that
$P(A \mid B)\geq P(A)$.
As a counterexample, suppose $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$,
let $A$ be the event that $X < 0.2$, and let $B$ be the event that $X > 0.6$.
Then $P(A) = 0.2$ as required but $P(A \mid B) = 0$.
I think the other limiting condition you're looking for is something like
$P(A^c \cap B)\leq P(A^c)$. This gives  you an upper bound on $p^2$,
but it turns out that $p^2 \leq 1$ (because $p^2$ is a probability) is a sharper upper bound in this exercise.

Thanks for the counter-example. It is quite an oversight on my part. I (wrongly) assumed that since the condition reduces the sample size it would increase the probability, but as you have correctly shown this does not apply if the events are mutually exclusive. Is that a fair summary of the error?

There are more possibilities than that; the case of mutually exclusive events is just an extreme example. We could change the realization of $B$ in the counterexample to make the value of $P(A\mid B)$ be any value between $0$ and $0.5$. If we also reduced the probability of $B$ to $0.2$ or less we could make $P(A\mid B)$ have any value between $0$ and $1$.

Understood. Thanks. A lot of high school textbooks get this very wrong...
